# Javascript Function With Square Brackets

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, brackets

I usually program in Python, but today I was trying to reverse engineer some Javascript code and I came across this line:

```
var ABC = DEF[XYZ];
```

`DEF` is a `function` that was defined earlier. It takes one argument. `XYZ` is a `string` that was created earlier, and it contains the results of running `DEF` previously.

I don't know much JavaScript, but it seems to me like it is defining a variable called `ABC` that contains the results of running function `DEF` with the argument `XYZ`. However, later on there is a line that goes `var GHI = ABC(JKL, DEF(MNO))` (`JKL` and `MNO` are both variables defined earlier).

What puzzles me is that `ABC` was defined as a variable, not a function. So I'm thinking this has something to do with the square brackets seen earlier.

So my question is: what is the purpose of those square brackets?

Comment: `DEF` is not a function, pretty sure. Can you show the source of `DEF`? You need to show us the context. If you can't link the exact code, cut it down and make one that behaves similarly.

Comment: Searching for: *JavaScript bracket* would have led you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors So it is referencing a property in an object and that property contains a function.

Comment: Functions are objects and `[...]` is used to get a property of an object. So `var XYZ = "call"; var ABC = DEF[XYZ];` is the same as `var ABC = DEF.call`

Comment: ...ultimately you can use development tools to see what values are produces from different expressions.

Comment: JavaScript could generate a warning message. I just found a bug in my code where I defined a function foo and tried to get its value by writing the expression foo[x]. This kept returning "undefined" and it took me about twenty minutes to see that I had used [] instead of ().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the purpose of those square brackets?

To access a member of an object.

It's not calling a function. It's attempting to access a member of the object `DEF` (without seeing the rest of the code, it's impossible to tell what kind of object `DEF` is, as you can use object member accession like that for any type of object that contains members, like plain objects, functions, arrays, etc.) For example:

```
var DEF = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

var XYZ = 'foo';

var ABC = DEF[XYZ];

console.log(ABC); // => 'bar'
```

As another example, `DEF` could also be an array, and if `XYZ` is a number, then it's accessing a specific index of that array.

## Update

If `DEF` is a function, you can still access members of it:

```
function DEF(arg) {
  // do something with arg
}

DEF.foo = function(str) {
   console.log('I am doing ' + str)
}

var XYZ = 'foo'

console.log(DEF[XYZ]) // => function() {}

var ABC = DEF[XYZ]

ABC('yoga') // => 'I am doing yoga'
```

You can call `DEF[XYZ](someArgument)` like this.

Comment: Basically, DEF is a function in the code that takes in a string as an argument, modifies the string, then returns the modified string.

Comment: @ejj28 the square brackets don't call a function. If you wanted to call `DEF` as a function, you'd call `DEF(someArgument)`

Comment: Yes, I understand that much. I didn't write this code, it's a piece of malware that I'm trying to analyze. DEF is called normally a few times before the line with the square brackets. I am just confused as to what the square brackets are doing.

Comment: @ejj28 the square brackets access a member of the function :) some property. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ejj28 the member can also be a function. So XYZ is a function that is a property of the DEF function.

Comment: So basically you're saying it could by referencing a variable or a function (XYZ) that is defined in the function DEF?

Comment: @ejj28 correct, if `XYZ` is referencing an object member of function `DEF` (and the object member is also a function).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, only the problem is XYZ is defined outside of the function DEF. XYZ is however the product of DEF.

Comment: @ejj28 If XYZ is a variable, then it can access any arbitrary member of the function object depending on the definition of XYZ. DEF[XYZ] is different than DEF.XYZ. If XYZ is defined as "foo", then it's the same as accessing DEF.foo when you use square bracket notation.

Comment: @ejj28 it may help if you read up a bit on object member accession in JavaScript

Comment: XYZ is defined like this: `var XYZ = DEF('foo');`

Comment: @ejj28 cool, this implies the return value of DEF is a string, and that string is the name of the property that we're then accessing on the DEF function. It's an extremely obfuscated way to write the code, which I'm sure is what the writer of the malware intended.

Comment: The value of XYZ is `clrpfguusxv`, which is not a member of DEF.

Comment: @ejj28 can you post the whole program to jsbin.com or something and provide a link?

Comment: Sure, but it's a trojan downloader, so exercise caution

Comment: Just give me a bit to upload it

Comment: Here it is: [http://jsbin.com/piqezozoze/edit?js,output](http://jsbin.com/piqezozoze/edit?js,output)

Comment: also DEF, ABC, XYZ etc aren't the actual names

Comment: I managed to reverse-engineer the code without figuring out that line. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Does this `const gen = () => [{id: 1,}];console.log(typeof(gen))` exist? It outputs `function`.